# magento2.2 override topmenu.php: _addSubMenu()

Tags: magento2.2, topmenu, override-block

I am trying to override the Topmenu Module Block but I can not understand why it fails.
I am trying to override the following method:

> magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Topmenu.php:_addSubMenu(...)

I have created the following folders/files:
app/code/Custom/Theme/Block/Html/Topmenu.php (If it works, "lala" should be appeared at the menu):

```
Topmenu.php
<?php

namespace Custom\Theme\Block\Html;

class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{
protected function _addSubMenu($child, $childLevel, $childrenWrapClass, $limit)
{
    $html = '';
    if (!$child->hasChildren()) {
        return $html;
    }

    $colStops = null;
    if ($childLevel == 0 && $limit) {
        $colStops = $this->_columnBrake($child->getChildren(), $limit);
    }

    $html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . ' ' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
    $html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass, $limit, $colStops);
    $html .= '<li>lala</li></ul>';

    return $html;
}

protected function _toHtml()
{
    $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu'));
    return parent::_toHtml();
}

}
```

app/code/Custom/Theme/etc/ has two files:

```
di.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Custom\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
</config>

module.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Custom_Theme" setup_version="0.0.1" />
</config>
```

And the registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Custom_Theme',
__DIR__
);
```

Is this approach correct? What do I miss?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Did you? I'm working on this right now. Would love to know.

Comment: @JustinP Anyone manage to get this working can you share?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the usage of the new block via XML. Add the following to your theme's default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
      <block class=“Vendor\Module\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move di.xml file from **etc** folder to **etc/frontend** folder and clear generated folder. Clear Magento cache. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

2 Things you seem to be correct.

1. Need to add sequence for Magento_Theme module in your module.xml file

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
>     <module name="Ey_Core" setup_version="1.0.0">
>         <sequence>
>             <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
>         </sequence>
>     </module>
> </config>
> ```

2. Then you should almost copy the entire Topmenu.php in our module. Because, most of the functions including __addSubMenu() are protected function. No protected functions are rewriteable. Thus we need to rewrite the public function where its being called. Like "getHtml()" function in our case.

Hope this helps anyone in need. Thanks.